# Count number of values of a list having same hash value in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, hash, inverted-index

I want to count number of values having same hash value.
    invertedindex element {{I1, I2},"book"}.

//mycode

```
for (String s1 : uniquewordslist) 

{

   if (invertedindex.containsKey(s1))

 {

    List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();

    l1 = invertedindex.get(s1);
    if (!l1.contains(key)) {
    l1.add(key);

    }
    invertedindex.put(s1, l1);
} 
else {
     List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();

     l2.add(key);

     invertedindex.put(s1, l2);


      }

   int count = Collections.frequency( ?????, invertedindex.values()); // 

   System.out.println(count);
```

it prints 0 always. what should be in ??? place

Comment: where is the hash value you are evaluating and why is `invertedindex.get(i).size()` not working for you to get the size of the list value for a string key?

Comment: myString==book 
consider it, please

Comment: I don't get count_  value. It should print 1. But it prints 0.

Comment: Why should it print 1? Please clarify, what do you want to count? You have an inverted index, thus, the element looks like `"book", ["string1", "string2", ..., "stringN"]`. Now, what do you want to count?

Comment: `invertedindex.values()` returns a Collection of all lists - those are **not flattened to a single list**. `Collections.frequency` counts for the number of occurrences in this collection of lists, but `myString` is **not** a list but a single element. Thus, it will be 0

Comment: please consider myString==book.

Comment: We have  considered it.  It is an expression.  What is your point?   If you want us to help you then you need to take the time to express your question clearly.  1) If you are asking us to help you to write code to do something, then you need to explain clearly what it is you are trying to do.  2) If you are asking us to help you debug some code, then you should provide an MCVE: a Minimal Compilable Verifiable Example.  3) When people ask for clarification you should take the time to understand what they are asking and then you should update your Question.

Comment: The problem is your question title says "Count number of values of a list having same hash value in java" ... but the code in the question seems to be doing something completely different.

Comment: @Zobs And I told you that `invertedindex.values()` returns a Collection of the values in the HashMap, which in fact is `Collection<List<String>>`. And you use `Collections.frequency` with a plain String `"book"` as second argument. That will indeed return 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if I understand exactly what u want but if u want to find in that map how many records have a value u should use it like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<String>> invertedindex = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add("firstitem");
    myList.add("seconditem");
    invertedindex.put("book", myList);
    invertedindex.put("book2", myList);
    int count_ = Collections.frequency(invertedindex.values(), myList);
    System.out.println(count_);
}
```

This will print 2.

Comment: `for (String s1 : uniquewordslist) 
{
   if (invertedindex.containsKey(s1)) {
  List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
  l1 = invertedindex.get(s1);
     if (!l1.contains(key)) {
  l1.add(key);
  }
  invertedindex.put(s1, l1);
 } 
    else {
   List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();
   l2.add(key);
      invertedindex.put(s1, l2);
    }
       int count = Collections.frequency( ????? invertedindex.values());
     
    System.out.println(count);'
        

e.g., 
    
    invertedindex element {{I1, I2},"book"}.
so count will return 2